# SQL Developer define a substitution variable using functions and concatenation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer, is it possible to define a variable as a construction based on another variable(s) to be used with a SPOOL?

For example:

```
define startdate='01-JAN-14'
define sdt=SUBSTR(&&startdate,4,3)

SPOOL &&sdt._File.csv
```

Giving me the output "JAN_File.csv"

I know that won't work because I've tested it and I've tried to research it, but is there a workaround to get to that same output?

Comment: Your title specifies SQL*Plus, yet your question identifies SQL Developer. Does it matter which querying tool? They do behave differently. Can you change the title and body of your question so that they are in agreement?

Comment: I have edited my title to more accurately reflect my needs. I am using SQL Developer. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not pretty but if you really wanted to you could use a bind variable as an intermediate step:

```
define startdate='01-JAN-14'

var bind_sdt varchar2(3);
exec :bind_sdt := SUBSTR('&&startdate',4,3);
column sub_sdt new_value sdt;
select :bind_sdt as sub_sdt from dual;

SPOOL &&sdt._File.csv
```

The [`column ... new_value` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#i2674387) is creating a substitution variable from the select-list item, which is the bind variable, which is the sub-string.

You could `set termout off` and back on around the `exec` and `select`, and `set verify off` if you aren't already doing so. You haven't said where the start date string is coming from so I've left that as a `define`.